# Saving Tableau workbooks into Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, tableau-api

I have a group be Tableau files .twbx files that I would like to store them into Hadoop. Is there a way to store them and then access them via Tableau desktop?

Comment: A .twbx file is a packaged workbook, which is comprised of a .twb Tableau workbook (essentially just XML), flat data sources (eg: Excel, CSV) or a Tableau Data Extract, and any custom images. 

Hadoop allows for "distributed processing of large data sets across clusters of computers using simple programming models". Why would you want to store a .twbx in Hadoop?

Answer (score 0):

[Tableau Server](http://www.tableau.com/products/server) is probably what you're looking for here.

Comment: Tableau server is very expensive, I am looking to do it on the hadoop cluster I already have, or have an s3 bucket to host the twbx files. Can I point Tableau to an s3 bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Again, you've got a couple options. In my setup, I keep my extracts on Tableau server and then have a daily task to push them to a Git repo; that's more for backup though.

If you're looking to store the active workbooks in the S3 bucket, you can configure Tableau Server with "worker nodes" to accomplish this. See the link to the Tableau Server Admin. Guide below, it's got an entire chapter on setting up a distributed server.

[Tableau Server Administrator's Guide](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/qs_distributed_server.html)